# Can any one suggest how to test leaflet maps using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to test fleet management software using selenium core java. But i have  no idea how to test maps and live tracking scenarios using selenium. can anyone give us best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding testing maps there are some easy actions e.g.

**Zooming in:**
driver.findElement(By.tagName(“Blabla”)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ADD));

**Zooming out:**
driver.findElement(By.tagName(“Blabla”)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT));

**Zooming reset:**
reset: driver.findElement(By.tagName(“Blabla”)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,”0″);

**Pop Up handling:**
driver.getWindowHandles()

But for live tracking I have no idea, first you should use the above mentioned actions, this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks in advance . BUT If we want to capture live Tracking how can we?